# Dropbox very high CPU usage without any actual data transfer

Tags: 12.04, cpu, overheating, dropbox, xubuntu

The Dropbox process constantly clocks more than 50% CPU usage sometimes going up to the higher 80s and 90s. At the same time it does not even upload/download the files it is supposed to. The progress is stuck at the same point and the dropbox daemon has not uploaded/downloaded more than one file in the last 24 hours. We are only talking about small files like pictures (~ 4-10 MB each). The effect this has on my laptop is that it overheats, sometimes with core temperatures up to 15-20 degrees above normal. The CPU utilization and temperature fall noticeably after I kill the dropbox daemon.

I have had this problem for more than a week now. I am using Xubuntu 12.04. I have more than enough local disk space available (8 GB in the disk where home and root are mounted) and 20 GB free space in my Dropbox account. I have 2 GB RAM.

I have also tried the following process (mentioned in this question: [Dropbox is taking too much CPU time. How can I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206396/dropbox-is-taking-too-much-cpu-time-how-can-i-fix-it)):

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox
rm -r $HOME/.dropbox*
sudo apt-get install nautlius-dropbox
```

But it made no difference to the problem at hand.

Comment: Have you check your Internet connection?

Answer (score 3):

First run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install cpulimit && sudo apt-get update
```

Then use a text editor like gedit or kate and put the following text in the file.

```
#!/bin/sh
dropbox start -i
cpulimit -e dropbox -l 15
```

save the file with a name like "cpulimit.sh." After saving go to the icon and right click, somewhere in the permissions section, there will be a box for "make executable" or something similar. Check that box. Go to the autostart program, which you can find by typing "startup" in unity ubuntu or autostart in kubuntu. Add a program, browse, find the .sh file you made and set ok. It should run every time you boot up. In the code above you'll notice there is a '15' that is the cpu useage max. You could probably set it even lower if you want (eg replace '15' with '8' or whatever). I don't know if there is a minimum or not.

Answer (score 1):

My situation might be different from yours, but I was having the exact same problem, however I'm now at a point where my Dropbox is working correctly.

Two things may have been a factor in getting my Dropbox into a working state.

First, specifics of the reinstall. For good measure I started with:

```
rm -r ~/.dropbox*
```

Next, I followed the instructions here: http://www.computeractive.co.uk/ca/computeractive-blog/2186872/fixing-dropbox-ubuntu-1204

Basically:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --purge remove nautilus-dropbox
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus-dropbox
```

Second, my situation might be different from yours in that I was trying to set Dropbox up on a secondary HDD since my primary HD is a smaller SSD.

I'd run into problems with Dropbox on secondary drives in the past, so as I was trying to troubleshoot the problem I always had it in the back of my mind that the issue could be related to trying to use a secondary drive.

After having no luck with the solutions you suggested here and others suggested elsewhere, I gave up and decided to see if it would behave more normally if I set my Dropbox up on the primary HDD.

I don't know if it was step 1 or step 2 that did the trick, but after that reinstall with my Dropbox folder on the primary SSH, Dropbox synced and behaved as expected.

Let me know if step 1 solves your problem, because I haven't looked into moving my Dropbox over to my secondary HDD, but I would like to.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check dropbox filestatus. it hogs cpu and memory when someting goes wrong. in my case the problem was in teamviewer file structure.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed by

```
rm -r ~/.dropbox
ln -s /mnt/win/Dropbox ~/Dropbox
```

Replace */mnt/win/Dropbox* with the path to the Dropbox folder from your secondary HDD.
Now start the Dropbox and set the location to *~/Dropbox*

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above but every time I re-installed it locked up one CPU core at 100%. Finally found if I followed all the steps to purge dropbox then did a clean install using the deb package from the dropbox website all runs fine.